# Adding share option for each blog article in listing

Tags: facebook, share, google-plus

I have a blog page with different articles as a list. Each article should have different share options (Facebook, Google+, Twitter, etc.). These share options should be accessible for each single article without the need to open the article itself.

How do I pass the information of the single article to it's share button? Right now the share plugin fetches it's informations from the page itself, not from the article.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Nothing. The question is if there are parameter to use with the official plugins.

Comment: "Right now the share plugin fetches it's informations from the page itself" - you have code that's doing that?

Comment: Then on what are you basing the statement "Right now the share plugin fetches it's informations from the page itself"? No. Why would I have code for what you're trying to do?

Comment: The plugins fetch there code from the og:tags. But these are only usable once per site. Are they?

Comment: It might help to edit your question with these details.

Comment: Why would this help? I don't use them because I don't need a "once per site" solution...

Comment: It might help to add more details to your question, because then we can understand what's going on and help you.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with the question... I also don't write that the sun is currently shining and I drive a black VW.

Right now I'm looking for an idea of how to start or a solution / tutorial someone else has already done on this issue.

Comment: "it has nothing to do with the question" - yes it does. The sentence "Right now the share plugin fetches it's informations from the page itself, not from the article." makes it sounds like you've got some code, but you want to change how it does things. As that's not the case, you should re-word the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a share button for each blog post and use the href attribute: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#target-url to point each button to a different blog post.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty straight forward. Wonder if I didn't get there by myself. Should also work for Facebook, because it then fetches the og:tags from the target URL. Thanks a ton!